# Server 2008 R2 Disk Managment Shows D:\ as 2 separate partitions

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, diskmanagement, partition

Original config of Poweredge T110 was a 250GB SATA. This was 40GB C:\ and rest D:. It only has 9% free, so, I decided to just put a 2TB drive in, and make it D:\ instead. So I extended my drive yesterday by putting a 2TB drive in, copied the data to the new 2TB drive, changed the letter from original D to Y, created the new D: with the new 2TB drive, and extended the original drive so that C: now has 100GB instead of 40GB.

However, funny thing is this:

When I look in Disk Management it shows the that D: has 2 separate partitions on Disk1
DATAPART1 (D:) 229.77 GB NTFS
DATAPART1 (D:) 1590.19 GB NTFS

Look in 'My Computer' the D: is 1.77 TB

I am just wondering why Disk Management shows this as 2 different partitions, and why I am not able to join them into 1. I am sure that this will not hurt saving data, but it just looks ugly when viewed.

Is there a way to join them into 1 in Disk Management for Server 2008 R2?

Comment: what happens after a reboot?

Comment: From what I am reading this will not matter for performance or usability of the server.

Comment: Can we get a screenshot?  And/Or how about the output of `Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskPartition`?

Answer (score 0):

Your drive was partitioned into 2 logical partitions at some point.  You can join them, but back everything up first as it is possible to erase all the data on that drive during the merge process.  You may not be able to join them if there is not enough free space to all the data from both of the partitions elsewhere on the machine or if one of the partitions contains the operating system.